# How to add strings to odd lines in a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to create a file with some arrays, and i need to add some data in all the odd lines in the file. also i need to remove some characters which i do with .translate()

```py
np.savetxt('new_arrary.txt', dsc)
mi_path = 'new_arrary.txt'
j = open(mi_path,'r')
lines = j.readlines()
j.close()
y = 0;
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if (i%2) != 0:
        lines[i-1] = str(kp[y])+' '+str(a[y])+' '+str(b[y])+' '+str(a[y])+' '+lines[i-1]
        y += 1
    lines[i] = lines[i].translate({ord('('): ord(' ')})
    lines[i] = lines[i].translate({ord(')'): None})
    lines[i] = lines[i].translate({ord('['): None})
    lines[i] = lines[i].translate({ord(']'): None})
    lines[i] = lines[i].translate({ord(','): None})

j = open(mi_path,'w')
for k in lines:
    j.write(k)
j.close()
```

with this i'm modifying lines but it is skipping some lines.
example: the codes modifies line 1 then line 5 skipping line 3

Comment: Can you give an example of what your `new_arrary.txt` looks like? (Preferably, both after the first line of your script, and after running the whole thing.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code throws a type error, so I would suggest something like this:

```
import re

with open('oddlines.txt') as fp:
    text = fp.read()

text = text.replace('(', ' ')         # use .replace(..)
text = re.sub(r'[)[\],]', '', text)   # .. and re.sub(..) to remove characters
lines = text.split('\n')

for i in range(1, len(lines), 2):         # from 1, skip every other..
    lines[i-1] = 'prefix:' + lines[i-1]   # I don't know what your kp[y] etc. are, so I'm just adding a string prefix

for line in lines:                        # then either print to screen
    print line

with open('oddlines.out', 'w') as fp:     # or to file..
    fp.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

with this text in `oddlines.txt`:

```
first (line)
(second line)
th[i]rd line
fourth, line
fifth,line
first (line)
(second line)
th[i]rd line
fourth, line
fifth,line
```

the code above prints:

```
prefix:first  line
 second line
prefix:third line
fourth line
prefix:fifthline
first  line
prefix: second line
third line
prefix:fourth line
fifthline
```